# Publishing a TypeScript package to NPM with two kind of installation (import and CDN)

Tags: typescript, npm

I want tu publish TypeScript project to [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/). I am using TypeScript Compiler (tsc) to transpiling **.ts** files of project to output **.js** file(s).

Thus, to generating output files I am using simple `tsc` command.

My **tsconfig.json**:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",
    "declaration": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5"
  }
}
```

After published I can install my package via:

```
npm install mypackagename
```

and using in typescript by:

```js
import MyLib from 'mypackagename'
```

It works! But I want to provide **two kind of installation**: via npm/import (as in the example above) and via [CDN](https://unpkg.com/):

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/mypackagename"></script>
```

Is it possible? Maybe I need to use some bundler instead TypeScript Compiler?

Now it is impossible beacuse I cannot use commonjs code directly in a browser.

Answer (score 1):

I finally used [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) bundler with configured: [`output.library`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibrary) and [`output.libraryTarget`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibrarytarget) as [UMD](https://github.com/umdjs/umd).

> `libraryTarget: 'umd'` - This exposes your library under all the module definitions, allowing it to work with CommonJS, AMD and as global variable. Take a look at the [UMD Repository](https://github.com/umdjs/umd) to learn more.

So, my [**webpack.config.js**](https://github.com/cichy380/simple-custom-event/blob/9b287f408c7f0b2b2be75fd28d3a50f3bc77a189/webpack.config.js) is:

```js
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'my-output-file.js',
    library: 'MyLib',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    libraryExport: 'default',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

...and [**tsconfig.json**](https://github.com/cichy380/simple-custom-event/blob/dfa899a53ff9caee296ca76b06d7281ef500cbdb/tsconfig.json) is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

Thanks to this my package can be installed via `import` in ES6/TypeScript:

```js
import MyLib from 'my-lib'
```

...or via [unpkg CDN](https://unpkg.com/):

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/my-lib@1.0.0"></script>
<script>
    var inst = new MyLib()
</script>
```

---

Source code of my project: https://github.com/cichy380/simple-custom-event